# Pipe, confused why pipe is important to execute my command, without it can't execute any following commands in the bat file

Tags: batch-file

```sh
generate-md --layout github --input folder1 --output folder2 | echo Yikes1 && @pause
echo Yikes2 && @PAUSE
```

This <s>bash</s> **batch program** doesn't execute the second line(exits abruptly) when I remove the pipe operator.

Can somebody explain why is it so?

I want to remove the pipe operator, help ?
Thanks in advance guys.

In suggestion to volunteer I tried new script... and its doing the same exit at the very first command [image]
And the result is this:[image]

Comment: I removed the _cmd_  tag from your question, because you are asking about bash, and not about the Windows batch language.

Comment: How is cmd different bash, what is bat file extension, what is the default file extension for cmd files?
Please help me understand I usually get confused a lot in these things. @user1934428

Comment: This is unrelated to extensions. The _cmd_  tag in SO refers to programs written in the Windows batch language. The _bash_ tag refers to programs written in the bash language. It's like Javascript and Basic - they don't have anything in common. **You** are the programmer, so you are supposed to know which language you are programming in.

Comment: On Windows, cmd-files usually have the extension `.cmd` or `.bat`. If you really want to talk about Windows Batch script, please ask a new question and remove all references to _bash_; otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: From your posting, I don't see how you actually invoke this script. As a bash script, you would run it by `bash SCRIPTNAME`, provided you have bash installed. The most popular bash implementations seem to be WSL (Ubuntu), Cygwin, and Git-bash.

Comment: Thanks a lot..but I still have doubt, are cmd files are windows batch files actually?

Comment: So, what does this opening file via double clicking the file does?? 
I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: Windows comes with two scripting languages: One is commonly called "Windows-Batch" (though I don't think this is the official name), which has its ancestor in the time around 1980, long before Windows was invented. The other one is called "Powershell". Of course there are many other ways to quickly write scripting programs in Windows. I am using mostly zsh, but you can choose from many others (bash, rexx, ksh, ruby, tcl, ....).

Comment: Windows maintains a list of so-called "associations", which associate a file extension with an application, and double-clicking on a file usually starts the associated application with this file as parameter. You can define your own associations, or just start your scripts from the command line, in which case you are free to choose, which application is being used. I prefer it doing things from the command line, but this is a matter of taste.

Comment: If `generate-md` is actually a [tag:batch-file] (with `.bat` or `.cmd` extension) you must use [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to return from it after completion…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe does not make any sense here, since `echo` ignores stdin anyway. Why did you put it there in the first place?

While I don't know how something can **exist** abruptly, you can structure your program in any way, as long as it does what you want it to do. Since `echo` returns status code 0 as long as stdout is not closed, I don't see any use for the `&&` statement separator either. Why don't you simply write

```
generate-md --layout github --input folder1 --output folder2 
echo Yikes1 
@pause
echo Yikes2
@PAUSE
```

which of course means that you need to have programs named @PAUSE and @pause in your PATH.

**UPDATE** : My answer was given under the assumption, that the OP was running a bash program, as he claimed to do in his original question. Meanwhile it seems that he is not using bash, so my answer is not relevant anymore.

Comment: soory for the exists typo, I meant exit actuallt.j

Comment: @SahilRajput : In case my answer does not provide a solution, you should post how your script looks like after you removed the pipe, so we have something to discuss. If it does provide a solution, please accept it.

Comment: The program exits even with your program at the very first line.

Comment: Then you either have other statements before it (for instance a `set -e`), or you don't run it with bash. Also, you should get an error message. Show your **complete** script, and post a transscript (or screenshot) of the complete output.

Comment: I'm running it with cmd i guess, if you see the added git image, you'll get what I'm doing actually.

Comment: You helped a lot, thanks brother.. but I guess there's some other problem than syntax, as it might be throwing error and thats why the program is getting exited asap in between the execution.(in the very first line only.) Thanks you helped a lot.

Comment: @SahilRajput : If you **really** want to stick with Windows Batch, run it from the command line using `cmd /k SCRIPTNAME`. It makes debugging easier. But from the viewpoint of most programmers, this language is a pain, so switching to something different may on the long term be better, depending on your needs. Some people are pretty fond of Powershell, or you go a completely different direction.